# Unable to hide MFC controls in a CDialog derived class

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog that is derived from our specific base class that is inturn derived from CDialog class
This dialog contains a combobox with combobox items in it (string)
There is a group box, labels, checkbox and a text box as well (I will call them grouped controls for this discussion)
If I select an item in index 0 from combo box, the Grouped controls are shown and if I select an item in index 1 from combo box, the group controls should be hidden
I have used the code to show or hide the controls as

```
void MyDerivedClass::HideMyControls(bool hide)
{
  int param = (false == hide)? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE;

  GetDlgItem(IDC_ENABLE_TP_DIRECTORY)->ShowWindow(param);//This is Checkbox control
  GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_NOTE)->ShowWindow(param);//This is label control
  GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_DIR_NAME)->ShowWindow(param);//This is label control
  GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_TP_DIRECTORY)->ShowWindow(param);//This is text control
  GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_TP_GRPBOX)->ShowWindow(param);//This is label control
  InvalidateRect(NULL); //NULL for testing
  UpdateWindow();
}
```

The issue is the controls are still seen on the screen even after the above method is called with true parameter. If I move some other window on top of the (supposed to be) hidden controls, then it is actually disappears. So this seems to be a refresh issue. My assumption is that the InvalidateRect and UpdateWindow should have taken care of repainitng this. but is not happening.
Tried with InvalidateRect(NULL) to paint the whole screen, but still no use.

Could you please suggest how I can hide the controls? any clean way of doing this?

Note: when the controls are (supposed to be) hidden but are still seen on the screen, I will not be able to perform any action on those controls (like setting checkbox or typing in the text box).
So I believe that the controls are marked as hidden but not painted.

Comment: Are you calling ShowWindow from the main thread? Also, you are assuming GetDlgItem will always return a valid pointer. You should enclose GetDlgItem in an if statement to prevent crashes

Comment: Is the dialog (or any control) owner-drawn?

Comment: The HideMyControl method is called from the same MyDerivedClass. This is called specifically in the event handler of the combo box selection changed.

Comment: @Asesh, Yes I am assuming the GetDlgItem will return a valid pointer! or NULL. Since these controls are present in these dialog I assume it will return a valid pointer. In any case I agree to put that defensive code as a best practise

Comment: Where is HideMyControls called from?

Comment: You didn't answer my question: Are you calling ShowWindow from the main thread?

Comment: What type of control is IDC_ENABLE_TP_DIRECTORY - what is special about's it's client rectangle, you don't say? What happens if you call `Invalidate();` only instead of the combination of `InvalidateRect(myRect); UpdateWindow()` because `Invalidate()` only is what I would expect to work.

Comment: Look, ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) and UpdateWindow() should be enough.  It is not working for some reason.  We'd like to help you.  We're asking questions to try to figure out what is going on.  If you want us to help you, please answer! Where is your function called from?  From a message handler?  Somewhere else?  What thread?

Comment: @BasyaPerlman IMO it should work even without calling `UpdateWindow` nor `InvalidateRect`.

Comment: As said early, this is called specifically in the event handler of the combo box selection changed. This is in the same Dlg class and it is the same thread as well.

Comment: @acraig5075, I was trying out on single control to get the rect and invalidate and updateWindow. and the control is a checkbox.

Comment: @Michael Walz -- I think it ought to also.  I am not sure about the UpdateWindow; sometimes it is needed.  I also do not think InvalidateRect is necessary.

Comment: @BasyaPerlman I often do ShowWindow/EnableWindow from an event handler (e.g if checkbox X is unchecked then disable control Y) and I never needed to call UpdateWindow.

Comment: I edited my post to make it clear. Sorry if that had caused confusion!

Comment: @Michael Walz: I think I did too.  Others to suggest the UpdateWindow; I don't remember if  I ever needed it.

Comment: @Asesh: if it is called from an event handler it is apparently called in the main GUI thread, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Murthy -- no owner drawn controls?  Are you running this over a debugger, by any chance?

Comment: @Murthy: have you confirmed that your function is actually being called when you expect it?

Comment: On a side note, you should always call `EnableWindow(FALSE)` if you call `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` for a control, because hidden controls can still be navigated to using the keyboard (TAB, Alt+Letter). This has nothing to do with the problem in this question though.

Comment: @Basya Perlman: They are not owner controls, I see the issue with and without debugger! Yes it calls from the function from when and where I expect it.

Comment: Something that does not make sense seems to be going on; I've shown/hid things many times, as have others who have posted here.  I'm trying to think of what could cause this...can we assume you've tried the standard response to "thinks are happening in my program that don't make sense" (clean and rebuild all :-) ) and the standard response to "something is happening in Windows that doesn't make sense" (reboot :-) ) because so far I can think of nothing I have experience with that could cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Is the operators' precedence correct on the line `int param = (false == hide)? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE;` ? Try to temporarily change every `ShowWindow` call parameter from `param` to `SW_HIDE` and see what happens.

Comment: Try `RedrawWindow()` instead.

Comment: Sounds more like an initialization issue. What are the property settings of the controls?